# RxJava Predicate Filter

Tags: java, rx-java, predicate

I want to find the 1st element in a List matching equality. :

1 Casting to its subtype

```
class EditorialBlock extends Block
```

2 filter the element

3 return the first element otherwise if not found return null.

Normally I will write it as

```
EditorialBlock findBlockByID(final List<Block> contentBlocks, final String identifier) {
    for (Block block : contentBlocks) {
        EditorialBlock item = (EditorialBlock) block; // 1 casting
        if (identifier.equals(item.getIdentifier())) { // 2 filter
            return item;  // 3 return the first element
        }
    }

    return null;
}
```

**How can this written with RxJava ?**
Can you also decompose the 4 steps : **0 Iterate, 1 Casting, 2 Filter, 3 Return first element or null**

Note : I was a fan of Guava's Predicate. In order to lower the dex count in my Android apps, I am going to replace RxJava by Guava's Predicates if possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work, Note that I used a lambda expression that requires Java 8.

```
EditorialBlock findBlockByID(final List<Block> contentBlocks, final String identifier) {
    return Observable.from(contentBlocks)
            .cast(EditorialBlock.class)
            .filter(x -> x.getIdentifier().equals(identifier))
            .toBlocking()
            .firstOrDefault(null);
}
```

The .cast() does the casting.

The .filter() does the filtering

the .firstOrDefault(null) is your third point.

The iterating happens deeper in the code.